# getting list of Linked contact in IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, ionic-framework

I want to develop an application where there are some contact pieces of information like listing contacts and creating and updating contact information, and also to list linked contacts.

Comment: Have you tried anything then share it. We cannot share a readymade solution.!

Comment: ionic or react native?